# Approximation Algorithm for Vertex Cover

Tags: algorithm, approximation, np, np-complete, polynomial-approximations

If `P` is not equal to `NP` can it be shown that there is no approximation algorithm which comes within `k` of the optimal vertex cover, where `k` is a fixed constant?

Comment: By 'within k' do you mean an absolute error or a relative error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is to be understood in terms of an additive error, such an algorithm does not exist. Aiming at a contradiction, suppose `A` is such an algorithm; this means that there is a nonnegative integer `k` such that for any graph `G`,

```
A(G) <= tau(G) + k
```

holds, where `A(G)` is the cardinality of the vertex cover of `G` generated by `A` and `tau(G)` denotes the cardinality of a minimum vertex cover. Let `k` be chosen minimal with respect to the existence of the mentioned algorithm. In particular, we have `k => 1`, since otherwise the vertex cover problem could be solved in polynomial time, which is impossible unless `P=NP` holds.

Let `G` be an arbitraty graph; create a graph `G'` by taking `k+1` isomorphic copies of `G`; then

```
tau(G') = (k + 1) tau(G)
```

holds. Furthermore we obtain the following.

```
A(G') <= tau(G) + k
       = (k + 1) tau(G) + k
```

Let `G*` be the isomorphic copy of `G` in `G'` with the smallest vertex cover generated by `A`; let `A(G*)` denote the size of this vertex cover. Aiming at a contradiction, we assume that

```
A(G*) >= tau(G*) + k
```

holds. This means that

```
A(G') >= (k + 1) A(G*)
      >= (k + 1) (tau(G*) + k)
       = (k + 1) (tau(G) + k)
       = (k + 1) tau(G) + k + k^2
       > (k + 1) tau(G) + k
```

holds, since `k > 0` holds. This is a contradiction to the approximation quality of `A`. This means that

```
A(G*) < tau(G*) + k
```

holds. As `tau(G*) = tau(G)` holds, this means that we have used `A` to generate a vertex cover of `G` with cardinality strictly smaller than

```
tau(G) + k
```

which is a contradiction, since `k` was chosen minimally and all construction steps can be carried out within a polynomially bounded running time, resulting in a runtime bound which is polynomially bounded as well.